# Efficiently select the best string from keys in a dict

Tags: python

I'm trying to read EXIF data from a file, specifically the title of an image. Sometimes there are multiple fields that need to be checked to see if a title was set. Right now, I'm doing this with a bunch of if statements, trying one at a time until the result is not none and if it is, applying a default title.

```
#Set the title
  m.title = exif.get('Xmp.dc.subject')
  if m.title is None:
    m.title = exif.get('Xmp.dc.title')
  if m.title is None:
    m.title = original_filename_noextension
```

My question is, is there an easier way to do this? The searching can get quite long if there are a lot of keys that need to be checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m.title = exif.get('Xmp.dc.subject') or exif.get('Xmp.dc.title') or original_filename_noextension
```

Should work. Note that this will 'coalesce' any falsey values, not just `None`.

Alternatively, you can write a function pretty easily:

```
def coalesce(*args):
   for a in args:
      if a is not None:
          return a
```

Usage:

```
m.title = coalesce(exif.get('Xmp.dc.subject'), exif.get('Xmp.dc.title'), original_filename_noextension)
```